# Is 'self' keyword Mandatory inside the class Methods?

Tags: python, class, object, self

I am python Begineer and i learned that first parameter  inside the method should be contain some 'self' keyword but i found the following program runs without self keyword can you explain about this below is my code...

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def get_biggest_number(*age):
        result=0
        for item in age:
            if item > result:
                result= item
        return result


Sam = Student("Sam",18)
Peter = Student("Peter",20)
Karen = Student("Karen",22)
Mike = Student("Michael",21)

oldest= Student.get_biggest_number(Sam.age,Peter.age,Karen.age,Mike.age)
print (f"The oldest student is {oldest} years old.")
```

Comment: First things first, `self` is not a reserved keyword in python, but a strong convention.

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the word 'self', in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self-in-python)

Comment: this is not exact duplicate but i mean 'self' is mandatory inside the class methods.

Comment: did you actually read what we posted? your exact question is answered several times in that thread.

Comment: thanks i was not actually clear on concept of decoraters, static method,class method so I got the above problem of 'self '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code you've posted has indentation errors within it, you should first indent methods and it's content, meaning that, methods are within class. On the other hand, `self` refers to instance, which calls specific method and gives access to the all instance data. For example

```
student1 = Student('name1', 20)
student2 = Student('name2', 21)
student1.some_method(arg1)
```

in the last call, behind the scenes `student1` is passed for self parameter of the method, meaning that all student1's data is available through `self` argument.

What you are trying is to use `staticmethod`, which has no data of the instance and is aimed to logically group class related functions without explicit instance, which does not require `self` in method definition:

```
class Student:
  ...
  @staticmethod
  def get_biggest_number(*ages):
    # do the task here
```

On the other hand, if you would like to track all student instances and apply get_biggest_number method automatically work on them, you just have to define class variable (rather than instance variable) and on each instance `__init__` append new instance to that list:

```
class Student:
  instances = list()  # class variable
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    # do the task
    Student.instances.append(self)  # in this case self is the newly created instance
```

and in `get_biggest_number` method you just loop through `Student.instances` list which will contain Student instance and you can access `instance.age` instance variable:

```
@staticmethod
def get_biggest_number():
  for student_instance in Student.instances:
    student_instance.age  # will give you age of the instance
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mistake classmethod with instance methods.
In python you can declare a method inside a class as classmethod.
This method takes a reference to the class as the first argument.

```py
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def get_biggest_number(self, *age):
        result=0
        for item in age:
            if item > result:
                result= item
        return result

    @classmethod
    def get_classname(cls):
        # Has only access to class bound items
        # gets the class as argument to access the class
        return cls.__name__

    @staticmethod
    def print_foo():
        # has not a reference to class or instance
        print('foo')
```

Answer (score 1):

`self` in python refers to the instance of the class that is created. Something like `this` in C# and Java. However there's some differences but in short: when you don't use `self` as input of a method, actually you're saying that this method does not need any instance, that means this method is a [`static method`](https://www.quora.com/Object-Oriented-Programming-What-is-a-static-method) and will never use any of class attributes.

In your example we can call `get_biggest_number` method with not even one instance, for example you can call this method just like this:

```
Student.get_biggest_number(20,30,43,32)
```

and the output will be `43`.

Answer (score 0):

The self keyword is used to represent an instance (object) of the given class. ... However, since the class is just a blueprint, self allows access to the attributes and methods of each object in python.

```
class ClassA:

    def methodA(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
```

let say ObjectA is an instance of the class.

Now when ObjectA.methodA(arg1, arg2) is called, python internally converts it as:

ClassA.methodA(ObjectA, arg1, arg2)

The self variable refers to the object itself and the code becomes as:

```
class ClassA:

    def methodA(ObjectA, arg1, arg2):
        ObjectA.arg1 = arg1
        ObjectA.arg2 = arg2
```