# Why class method must have self parameter in python?

Tags: python, methods, self

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

I know why self is used in this code. This can take different students and make differnt attributes

```
student1 = Student()
student2 = Student()
...
studentn = Student()
------------------------------------

student1.name
student2.name
...
studentn.name
```

but I can't understand why this code below needs self parameter.

```
class Student:
    def study():
        print("I'm studying")


Student().study()
```

output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/directory/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    Student().study()
TypeError: study() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Because when you call an instance method, the receiving object is passed as an argument to the method. If the method can't accept that object, you get an error. If you don't want the function to accept a `self` parameter, you don't have to make it an instance method.

Comment: well, BTW your first code that you claim to understand, is not even valid. It will throw you the same error, just different numbers... `__init__ takes 2 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The first argument of every class method, including init, is always a
>   reference to the current instance of the class. By convention, this
>   argument is always named self. In the init method, self refers to the
>   newly created object; in other class methods, it refers to the
>   instance whose method was called

More on the self variable [here](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/)

Answer (score 4):

Because methods are passed the instance they're called on, regardless of if the method needs it or not.

If you don't want to need to have the parameter, make it a "static method":

```
class Student:
    @staticmethod
    def study():
        print("I'm studying")
```

Answer (score 2):

**you can use this code if not add 'self'**

```
class Student:
    def study():
        print("I'm studying")


Student.study()
```

output:
I'm studying

Comment: You shouldn't really do this.

Comment: Wow, this is interesting. This give me some clue

Comment: @juanpa-arrivillaga Your prohibitive statement requires justification.

Answer (score 0):

This is just how python works when you do instance.method(). Method receives the instance as the first parameter. Note that:
`Student().study()` is equivalent to

```
student = Student()
student.study()
```

Answer (score 0):

Self is not a keyword, It's just a convention. Also, when you pass self to the method of a class you are referring to that particular object by using self(as a class can have multiple objects and all have access to that method), self gives you the option to use the attributes of the class in that method by using self.att . You can make the output of the function study as attribute like self.study="I am studying" that will better suit your purpose. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58426672/is-self-keyword-mandatory-inside-the-class-methods) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self) .

Answer (score 0):

Guido Van Rossum (the maker of python) wrote a blogpost in which he told [why explicit self has to stay.](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because whenever a method is called on an object, Python automatically passes the method the object that called it.

Answer (score -2):

When creating function inside a class you need to pass `self` as argument:

```py
class Student:
    def study(self):
        print("I'm studying")
```

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't do anything to explain to the OP why their code fails